# Dojo functions with underscore in front

Tags: function, dojo, underscores

Why do some DOJO functions have underscore in front of the function name. Are this functions any different to the other functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything beginning with an underscore is not part of the public API.

If you know java or C#, think `private, protected internal/package private`

The Dojo team does a pretty good job maintaining backward compatibility on the public API, but there is no such guarantee with the non-public API.  So if you write a custom widget which overrides a function that begins with an underscore, it could break on an upgrade.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/developer/styleguide.html

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, these are local variables / functions.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, here is a post from SitePen about the topic. Hope this helps!

http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2013/11/05/dojofaq-underscore-module-name/